# Volume calculation $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2y$ and $z^2\sin^2(b)=(x^2+y^2)\cos^2(b)$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

They give me two surfaces
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2y;\quad \quad z^2\sin^2(b)=(x^2+y^2)\cos^2(b)$$

If I am not mistaken, it is a sphere displaced on the $y$ axis; and a cone with an origin vertex and angle with respect to the $XY$ plane equal to $b$

I am asked, by changing from variable to cylindrical and to spherical, to calculate the volume that comprises the intersection of these figures.

I started with sphericals. It comes to this: if we call the $(r,\phi,\theta)$-coordinates where $r$ is the radius, $\phi$ the angle of projection on the $XY$ and $\theta$ the angle to the $Z$-axis, we would have $r=a^2\sin(\phi)\sin(b)$ and $\theta=b$.

The thing is, what represents the limits of the cut? I mean, I'd like to reason with you, but I just don't see the limits very well. I've tried, but I'm getting nonsense.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r42Vj.jpg)

Comment: The second is not a cone. It's a double paraboloid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2y\\
z^2\sin^2\beta = (x^2+y^2)\cos^2\beta$

[image]
converting to spherical

$x = \rho\cos\theta\sin\phi\\
y = \rho\sin\theta\sin\phi\\
z = \rho\cos\phi$

Substitute into the original equations.

$\rho^2 = a^2\rho\sin\theta\sin\phi\\
\rho = a^2\sin\theta\sin\phi$

$\rho^2\cos^2\phi\sin^2\beta = \rho^2\sin^2\phi\cos^2\beta\\
\tan^2\beta = \tan^2\phi\\
\phi = \beta, \pi-\beta$
(We only care about solutions for $\phi$ in $[0,\pi]$)

$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\beta}^{\pi-\beta}\int_0^{a^2\sin\theta\sin\phi} \rho^2\sin\phi \ d\rho\ d\phi \ d\theta$

And I will leave the integration to you.

This is the single volume inside the sphere outside the double cones.  If you want the two volumes top and bottom, subtract this from the volume of the sphere.

Comment: Okay I understand but why does $\phi$ goes from $\beta$ to $π-\beta$?

Comment: $\beta, \pi-\beta$ mark the edges of the cone.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but a visualization that will perhaps help:

[image]

Comment: The thing is, I don't know how to take the limits of integration. I added a picture. I assume they're asking for these volumes: the top and bottom, right?